# How to pick PDF file in android

Tags: android

I try to download a pdf file from my android phone to Firebase but when I click on the button to select a file in my phone, I get this error: Application not found to perform this action.

Which is quite odd since I have the Adobe Acrobat Reader pdf reader in my phone that allows me to read all the pdf files of my phone.

Please tell me what's wrong with my code.

ps: I execute my code on Android 4.0.3

that is my code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_PDF_CODE);
```

Comment: Have you given your application permission to read files on the device ?

Comment: yes I add permission `read external storage` in my manifest

Comment: This might be a shot in the dark as I don't think its needed on Android 4, but check the device settings, looking for apps and find your app. There should be a section where permissions are listed, see if you can maybe turn on read external storage.

Answer (score 3):

Try this its working code

```
   Intent intentPDF = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intentPDF.setType("application/pdf");
            intentPDF.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intentPDF , "Select Picture"), PICK_PDF_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try with this way :

**Like :**

```
String[] mimeTypes =
        {"application/pdf"};

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    intent.setType(mimeTypes.length == 1 ? mimeTypes[0] : "*/*");
    if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    }
} else {
    String mimeTypesStr = "";
    for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
        mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
    }
    intent.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0,mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
}
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"ChooseFile"), REQUEST_CODE_DOC);
```